# How to write region specific logic separate from normal flow?

Tags: java, java-8, object-oriented-analysis

I have a class name ProductValidation, and in that class ther eis function named validate which iterate over list of products. Inside that function which checks for region. lly, there are other functions which have region specific check. I want to move this region specific checks to a different class. How the code below can be improvised ?

```
class Product{
    int id,
    long price;
    String region;

    Product(int id, long price, String region){
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.region = region;
   }

   // getters for id,price and locId
}

Class ProductValidation{
   public static validate(List<Product> list, long[] prices){
     for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
          if(list.get(i).getRegion().equals("ASIA"){ 
            long[i] = 0;
          }
      }
}


long[] price = {40, 90, 40};

List<Product> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new Product(1,100, "ASIA"));
list.add(new Product(1,100, "AUS));
list.add(new Product(1,100, "EUROPE"));

 // call ProductValidation.validate(list, price)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the `price` stored in the array of that name and the `price` stored in the `Product`'s field of the same name? And why do you want to set a price to zero; what is it supposed to mean? This looks very much like an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 1):

You can represent that test as a `BiPrerdicate`

```
BiPredicate<Product, String> productRegionSearch = (p,s) -> p.getRegion().equals(s);
```

and invoke it as

```
if(productRegionSearch.test(list.get(i), "ASIA"))...
```